# amazon payfort capture operation error: "Operation not allowed : CAPTURE"

Tags: php, laravel, curl, amazon-pay, payfort

I have started using the "*Amazon payfort payment service*", but I'm facing some issues.
I am trying to get the transaction information based on the [Api example](https://paymentservices-reference.payfort.com/docs/api/build/index.html#capture-operation), but I always get the error "Operation not allowed: CAPTURE"
This is my curl request:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -XPOST -d '{   "command": "CAPTURE",   "access_code": "Xw************",   "merchant_identifier": "51*****",   "merchant_reference": "ORDR.90342",   "amount": 350100,   "currency": "SAR",   "language": "en",   "fort_id": "169996200001495787",   "signature": "942b11d7e204d433913383ca68fa03eb0c5eca34cec6c44f8e6869d4fcea795c" }' 'https://sbpaymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi'
```

And this is the server response:

```
{"response_code":"00034","amount":"350100","signature":"650003b1b6c8243a7ef7daec851a69cb0795212a92c6acc30b283d960c521224","merchant_identifier":"51*****","access_code":"X****************","language":"en","fort_id":"169996200001495787","command":"CAPTURE","response_message":"Operation not allowed : CAPTURE","merchant_reference":"ORDR.90342","currency":"SAR","status":"00"}
```

Comment: `-XPOST` is not a thing, you probably meant `-X POST` there.

Comment: And `-d` implies POST request already, so you should really not need `-X POST` to begin with. Isn’t contained in the cURL example they provide on that page you referred to, either.

Comment: Thank you!, but I think the problem is not in request structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the purchase request, not the capture operation.
i changed the command from `PURCHASE` to `AUTHORIZATION`, and now the capture request is working successfully. Thank you everyone.